# UISegmentedControl if statement

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying learning the UISegmentedControl and want to figure out how to get it to work within an if statement to return one value based on selection and another value based on the other selection. There is only two values the UISegment can return - "Fixed" or "Varibale". The code below does not work but gives an idea what I want. The two variables are predefined.

```
  @IBAction func calPenalty(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let startDate = termStartDate.text
    let mortgageTerm = Double(mortgageTermLabel.text!)
    let discount = Double(mortgageDiscountLabel.text!)
    let mtgCashback = Double(casbackRecieved.text!)
    let mtgBalance = Double(mortgageBalance.text!)
    let rate = Double(currentRate.text!)
    //let mortgageType = mortgageType

    let lender = Global.selectedRate
    if let oneYear = Double((lender?.oneYear)!),
        let twoYear = Double((lender?.twoYear)!),
        let threeYear = Double((lender?.threeYear)!),
        let fourYear = Double((lender?.fourYear)!),
        let fiveYear = Double((lender?.fiveYear)!) {

        let maturityDate = (getMaturityDate(startdate: startDate!, termMonths: Int(mortgageTerm!)))

        let monthsToMaturity = daysBetweenDates(endDate: maturityDate)/365*12

        let comparisonTerm = (IRDComparisonTerm(monthsToMaturity: monthsToMaturity))

        let cashback = cashbackRepayment(cashbackRecieved: mtgCashback!, mtgTerm: Double(mortgageTerm!), mthsToMaturity: Double(monthsToMaturity))

        print(cashback)


        var comparisonRate: Double = 0

        switch comparisonTerm
        {
        case 12:
            comparisonRate = oneYear

        case 24:
            comparisonRate =  twoYear

        case 36:
            comparisonRate =  threeYear
        case 48:
            comparisonRate = fourYear
        case 60:
            comparisonRate = fiveYear

        default:
            comparisonRate = 0

        } // end switch statement

       print(comparisonRate)

        let IRD = IRDPenalty(IRDComparisonRate: comparisonRate, mtgBalance: mtgBalance!, mthsToMaturity: Double(monthsToMaturity), discount: discount!, currentRate: rate!)

        let threeMthsInterestPenalty = threeMonthsInterestPenalty(mtgBalance: mtgBalance!, mtgRate: rate!)

        print (IRD)
        print (threeMthsInterestPenalty)


        var penalty: Double = 0
       // var totalPenalty: Double = 0

        if IRD > threeMthsInterestPenalty {

            penalty = IRD + cashback
        }else{

            penalty = threeMthsInterestPenalty + cashback
        }



      // totalPenalty = penalty + cashback

         calculationLabel.text = String(penalty)


    }

}
// triggers result based on value selected
   @IBAction func valueChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        calculationLabel.text = String(penalty)

    case 1:
        calculationLabel.text = String(threeMthsInterestPenalty + cashback)

    default:
         calculationLabel.text = String(penalty)
    }


}
```

Edit: I am still working on this problem. I have updated to the above code to show all the code within the IBAction. The @IBAction does not work as the variables are undefined based on where they are posted within the code. The Storyboard has a UIsegmentedControl with to values "Fixed and Variable. If the user selects fixed then I want it to show as per the IBAction for UISegement Control.

Comment: There's no context to the code you posted. What are all the variables being used? What is it that you are actually trying to do? And a `UISegmentedControl` doesn't return any values. All you can do is determine which segment is selected.

Comment: Which variables are undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to check when the value of your segmented control changes, and you want to do it programmatically, you firstly need to register a target-action method using `valueChanged` constant. Then, write up your `valueChanged` function. Check [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol) out for more information.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // Reference from Storyboard or Interface Builder
    @IBOutlet weak var mortgageType: UISegmentedControl!

    // For set up a UISegmentedControl programmatically
    var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        // Programmatically setup
        let items = ["Cinnamon", "Clove"]
        segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: items)
        segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        segmentedControl.frame = CGRect(x: 120, y: 200, width: 200, height: 30)
        segmentedControl.tintColor = UIColor.black
        segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.valueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        self.view.addSubview(segmentedControl)
    }

    @IBAction func valueChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            print("Hi")

        case 1:
            print("Bye")

        default:
            print("Nothing")
        }
    }
}
```

If you reference your UISegmentedControl from Storyboard and Interface Builder. You should also add an action to it.
[image]

**Update to the edited question**

```
@IBAction func calPenalty(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if mortgageType.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        print("Fixed")
    } else {
        print("Variable")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've added more comments to my original post. I am still working towards a solution.

Comment: If you use interface builder or Storyboard you don't have to set up your `segmentedControl` and even `addTarget` if you know how to add an action from the UI. According to your edited question "Do something" would be "hi" and "Do other things" would be "bye".

Comment: I am not sure what I would need to add to the setup function. This is the details for my controller "@IBOutlet weak var mortgageType: UISegmentedControl!"

Comment: Check my edited answer for full code of how to implement it either using UI or programmatically.

Comment: Thank for reworking the code. I apologize but I left one thing out. I am trying to use the SegmentController within an @IBAction with the sender being a button. Can you have two senders within the same action?

Comment: Sure, in my example, the `valueChanged` is used for both `mortgageType` and `segmentedControl`. However, if the sender is also a UIButton change `sender: UISegmentedControl` to `sender: Any`.

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting this. I am using your code and I get an error only instance methods can be declared IBAction. Swift want me to remove IBAction and when I do the error does away but the code does not work.

Comment: I realized my problem is I am trying to use a UISegmentControl as a toggle when it has to be an action.

Comment: No worries, please accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: I posted an edit to my original post. I really wish there were radio buttons in Swift.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147413/discussion-between-kevin-proctor-and-lawliet).